# Choosing a modal verb: will or can

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

In the sentences below, which one is correct and/or formal?

> Will you accept this credit card?

or

> Can you accept this credit card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a correct one would be *"Do you accept credit cards?"*. *Can you* lends itself to being a favor, and *will you* sounds a little aggressive.

Comment: I'm not sure about the UK, but here in the US I think *cards* would typically be plural: "Do you accept credit cards?"  Informally, *take* is often used in place of *accept*.

Comment: @snailplane here in the UK, I always hear "Do you accept/take credit cards?", never in singular. Does the singular use really sound British? :)

Comment: @Nico No, but I'm not familiar with every detail of BrE and the author's profile placed them in the UK, so I didn't want to assume.  If you can confirm it's a simple typo, we can edit the answer to include the s :-)

Comment: @Nico - I agree that it's usually in the plural, unless the question is about one particular card in particular. For example (this is me, holding my Discover card): _"Would you take this credit card?"_

Comment: Another one of the million idiosyncrasies of the English language!

Answer (score 2):

The two questions have different meanings.

*Can you accept the credit card?*  is asking someone if they have the capability to accept the card.

*Will you accept the credit card?*  is asking someone who has the capability if they are willing to accept the card.

Just because someone *can* accept a card does not mean that they *will* accept it.

Comment: Most vendors that _can_ accept a credit card _will_ accept a credit card. :^) But you bring up a great point: _Can you take my dog for a walk?_ and _Will you take my dog for a walk?_ Those are less likely to have the same answer – unless I really enjoy being with your dog.